# C++ O2 Memory leak when using const reference to literal in class

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-leaks, machine-code

When I was implementing a program, I found that my program behaves differently when switching from `-g` to `-O2` in either g++ or clang++.

The simplified code is:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
class A {
 public:
  explicit A(const int64_t &zero_);
  const int64_t& zero;
};
A::A(const int64_t &zero_):
  zero(zero_) {
  std::cout << "zero=" << zero << std::endl;
}
int main() {
  A st(0);
  size_t p;
  std::cin >> p;
  std::cout << "zero=" << st.zero << std::endl;
}
```

Assume the standard input is 1, and the excepted output (in the last line) is zero=0 since the variable `zero` is a const reference.

When compiled with `g++ -g -o b.o b.cc`, the program behaves normally.

However, when compiled with `g++ -O2 -o b.o b.cc`, the output is `zero=1`

In fact, it outputs the value of `p`.

Is this a bug or expected behavior?

Tested on Debian10 amd64

Comment: the generated assembly shows that the compiler is reusing the stack for both `p` and `st.zero` I'm not really sure why though.

Comment: same behavior [here](https://onlinegdb.com/rk1ncHoZI). Initially thought it will be compilation error as `int` is passed instead of `reference`

Comment: @Alex.-Address of `p` and `st.zero` are same

Comment: You're storing a reference to a temporary, and using that reference long after the end of the expression that the temporary belongs to. Why would you expect that to work?

Comment: @ruakh why isn't a compiler error for `A st(0);` ?

Comment: (By the way, the title of this question says "memory leak", but there's no [memory leak](https://www.google.com/search?q=memory+leak) in the question. I think you've misunderstood that term.)

Comment: It surprises me that `A st(0)` doesn't invoke a compile error. Most languages that support references enforce that you provide a properly instanced variable for it.

Comment: @TruthSeeker: It's not a compile error because C++ allows you to take a constant reference to a temporary. (That's actually an *extremely* common pattern.) But you know nothing about the lifetime of the underlying object, so you can't just keep the reference lying around.

Comment: @Havenard C++ is not 'most languages'.  If you want to shoot yourself in the foot, go ahead.

Comment: @PaulSanders Evidently. I guess the others learned from it's mistakes. Sadly the one thing they can't learn from it is speed.

Comment: @ruakh Is it because of `const` reference?

Comment: @TruthSeeker: Yes.

Comment: @Harvanard Many undefined behaviours and similar in the C++ standard are "no diagnostic required".. The compiler is (usually) not required to diagnose anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`A::zero` is a dangling reference and hence UB.

When you construct `st`, a temporary is created to pass the parameter. This temporary goes out of scope at the end of the statement but `st.zero` is still referring to it.  Therefore, mysterious things happen when you try to use it.

The difference between -g and -O2 is coincidental.  With UB, different things can happen depending on the exact circumstances.

Comment: `A::zero` is reference to what?

Comment: @TruthSeeker The member variable `zero` in an object of class `A`

Comment: @TruthSeeker Impossible to tell exactly. It's a reference to the `0` he passed as parameter in the constructor, but because `0` is not a variable, it goes out of scope just after the constructor is called.